# Sum of values in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, xcode, sum, nsdictionary

I am looking for the efficient and easy way to sum all of the values in NSDictionary.

For example, if I have NSDictionarys like:

```
NSDictionary * first = @{@"A": [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                         @"B": [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                         @"C": [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                         @"D": [NSNumber numberWithInt:4]};

NSDictionary * second = @{@"A": [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                         @"B": [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                         @"C": [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                         @"D": [NSNumber numberWithInt:4]};
```

I would like to get a NSDictyonary

```
NSDictionary * sum = @{@"A": [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                         @"B": [NSNumber numberWithInt:4],
                         @"C": [NSNumber numberWithInt:6],
                         @"D": [NSNumber numberWithInt:8]};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDictionary * first = @{@"A": [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                         @"B": [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                         @"C": [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                         @"D": [NSNumber numberWithInt:4]};

NSDictionary * second = @{@"A": [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                          @"B": [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                          @"C": [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                          @"D": [NSNumber numberWithInt:4]};
NSMutableDictionary *Third=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
for (NSString* key in [first allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"%@",key);

    int a=[[first objectForKey:key]integerValue];
    int b=[[second objectForKey:key]integerValue];

    int c= a+b;

    [Third setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:c]  forKey:key];

    }

NSLog(@"%@",Third);
```

**Updated for Distinct Key**

```
NSArray *Key_of_First=[first allKeys];
NSArray *Key_of_Second=[second allKeys];

for (int j=0; j<Key_of_First.count; j++) {

    int a=[[first objectForKey:[Key_of_First objectAtIndex:j]]integerValue];
    int b=[[second objectForKey:[Key_of_Second objectAtIndex:j]]integerValue];

    int c= a+b;

    [Third setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:c]  forKey:@"Your Key Name which you give"];

}

  NSLog(@"%@",Third);
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of something like this, but I hope I can get this quicker :D One question, what happened if some key exist in first but not in second dictionary?

Comment: No need for `[first allKeys]`; fast iteration works with dictionaries too. Just say: `for (NSString *key in first) {...}`.

Comment: If a key doesn't exist in the second dictionary, the second dictionary's value for that key will be nil. Effectively, `b` will become `0` since `[nil integerValue]` is `0`, which means that the result dictionary will be the value from the first dictionary.

Comment: @MarkoZadravec, Please let me know if you have any problem. Is this helpful to you?

Comment: Yes thanks, it was helpful. Thanks four your time :D

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one :

```
 NSDictionary * sum = @{@"A": [NSNumber numberWithInt:
                                  ([[first objectForKey:@"A"] intValue]+
                                   [[second objectForKey:@"A"] intValue])],
                           @"B": [NSNumber numberWithInt:
                                  ([[first objectForKey:@"B"] intValue]+
                                   [[second objectForKey:@"B"] intValue])]

                                                     };
```

Comment: this approach is good if you know what keys you have in advance, which I don't.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this... may be this will help you..

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)sum :(NSDictionary *)first :(NSDictionary *)second
{

    NSMutableDictionary * sum =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                init];
    NSArray *keysOfFirst =[first allKeys];
    for (id key in keysOfFirst)
    {
        NSNumber * num =[NSNumber numberWithInt:([[first objectForKey:key] intValue] + [[first objectForKey:key] intValue])] ;
        [sum setObject:num forKey:key];
    }

    return [sum autorelease];
}
```

Comment: just pass your dictionaries as arguments. if keys are not same , then the object for key will return nil and hence sum will be the first no' plus zero.